# Expo EAS - Minimum Deployent Target

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

My local build returns error like:

```
 compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0
```

But I've found nothing how to switch my deployment target from 12.0 to 13.0?

How can we change our deployment target on Expo EAS.